# Is it necessary to register a Xamarin account to use it?

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

Recently, I just installed Xamarin on Visual Studio Community 2015. Well, I don't know much about it. I was trying to create my first project. But, When I tried to create an Empty Xamarin.Forms Project. It opens a window to log in to Xamarin Account.

Is it really necessary to have an account before using Xamarin?
I don't think so...

Answer (score 3):

Update to Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Visual Studio 2015 has old Xamarin packages that may still require sign in to a legacy Xamarin account. There are no longer any Xamarin accounts, except for Xamarin forums.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be logged in to develop with Xamarin. 
They control license acceptance by logged users.

To download some components, you will need to be logged in too.